# CMake fails to find packages after removing conda

Tags: cmake, anaconda, conda

I removed conda by following option A in the [documentation](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall), i.e. I simply removed the 
`~/anaconda3` directory and got rid of the relevant line in my `~.bashrc`. However, when I call `cmake` in a different project of mine, cmake still tries to link to libraries installed with anaconda:

```
$ cmake .. 
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.9/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1247 (file):
  file STRINGS file "/home/USERNAME/anaconda3/include/boost/version.hpp"
  cannot be read.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  dbklib/CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package)


-- Boost version: 0.0.0
-- DBKLIB: 
CMake Error at pydbk/pybind11/tools/FindPythonLibsNew.cmake:95 (message):
  Python config failure:

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  pydbk/pybind11/tools/pybind11Tools.cmake:16 (find_package)
  pydbk/pybind11/CMakeLists.txt:33 (include)
```

How do I get rid of anaconda completely? Can I still somehow run the `anaconda-clean` tool without having conda?

Comment: Clean project's build directory and rerun `cmake`. Or delete `CMakeCache.txt` file in that directory and rerun `cmake`.

Comment: Brilliant, that did the trick. Should have known better and tried that first... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After modifying installed packages set (especially after removing the package), when rebuild CMake project it is needed to **clean CMake cache** of that project, so CMake will recheck results of previous searching of packages.

CMake cache may be cleared by removing `CMakeCache.txt` file from build directory, or by completely cleaning the build directory.